# Tab bar first icon is selected by default in Rhodes

Tags: rhodes, rhomobile

I am  having a problem in tab bar(when the application loads initially
by default it displays first tab bar icon is selected and it redirect
to that page also)

Here is my code

```
class AppApplication < Rho::RhoApplication
 def initialize
   tabbar = [
     {:label => 'search',  :action => '/app/Search', :icon => '/
public/images/Icons/search.png', :reload => true},
     {:label => 'map',  :action => '/app/Map', :icon => '/public/
images/Icons/map.png', :reload => true},
     {:label => 'menu',  :action => '/app/Account', :icon => '/public/
images/Icons/menu.png', :reload => true},
     {:label => 'businesses',  :action => '/app/Work', :icon => '/
public/images/Icons/businesses.png', :reload => true},
     {:label => 'reviews',  :action => '/app/Review', :icon => '/
public/images/Icons/reviews.png', :reload => true}
   ]
   Rho::NativeTabbar.create( :tabs => tabbar, :place_tabs_bottom =>
true)
   @@toolbar = nil
   super
 end
end
```

- Here (when the application loads initially "search" icon is selected
  by default, also it redirect to the search page , but in rhoconfig.txt
  srart path is `'/app/Map'`

How to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A tab bar is going to override the start path in your config, and it's always going to load the first tab by default.

You can call Rho::NativeTabbar.switch_tab(1) (zero index based) after the tab bar has been created to switch your app to whatever tab you want.